# Best solution to redirect a site internally

Tags: html, web, seo

I have a site hosted on a commercial provider and all site were developed on /portal folder.

Until today I redirect the site using frameset:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Titulo</title>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="xxx" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<meta name="description" content="xxxx">
</head>
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME SRC="http://www.test.com.br/portal" NORESIZE>
<body></body>
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

Now, the host provider suggests me to use:

```
<script>window.location='http://www.test.com.br/portal';</script>
```

Is this faster or better than the frameset approach ?
Is Google or other search engine will continue to search for the content?

Comment: Can you use a server side language like PHP?

Comment: You could configure your HTTP daemon to do a `30x` redirect. You won't even need to have a redirect page anymore.

Comment: My concern is to speed at maximum the redirect. I understand that using a server side language will degrade a bit the redirect. Am I right?

Comment: As I am using an host provider, I don't have access to the apache configuration so I think change HTTP daemon is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You have different ways to redirect to another page. If you're using a **server-side language** like php you can use this (before the headers has been sent):

```
header("Location: http://www.test.com.br/portal");
```

using **HTML** you can do this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.test.com.br/portal">
```

Using **Javascript** you can do this:

```
<script>window.location='http://www.test.com.br/portal';</script>
```

The best way, in my opinion, is the first because of you can also specify the type of redirect (permanent or temporary) and this is better from a SEO point of view. Google and the other search engines will be able to crawl your page easily if you choose the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this tag to the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.test.com.br/portal"/>
```

Comment: Could you explain Why this is better than frameset option?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons it's better than using framesets.

In addition to

```
<script>window.location='http://www.test.com.br/portal';</script>
```

you can put a link to that page into your HTML body, something like this:

```
<p>You will now be redirected to another page.<br/>
If it didn't happen, use this link:
<a href="http://www.test.com.br/portal">http://www.test.com.br/portal</a></p>
```

But the solution with php's header function (Aurelio De Rosa's answer) is better indeed.